# Finding distance between 2 coordinates in solidity

Tags: solidity

It is said that distance is equal to the following formula:

```
distance = sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 )
```

I do this exact formula in the function below. However, the problem I run into is when `x2` is less than `x1`, for example, I get an error because uint256 can't be negative.

Does anyone know how I can account for this in solidity when calculating distance?

```
function getDistance(uint256 x1, uint256 x2, uint256 y1, uint256 y1, ) private view returns(uint256) {
  return sqrt(((x2 - x1)**2) + ((y2 - y1)**2));
}

function sqrt(uint x) private pure returns (uint y) {
  uint z = (x + 1) / 2;
    y = x;
    while (z < y) {
        y = z;
        z = (x / z + z) / 2;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using uint256 use int256 so you can accept negative number

Answer (score 0):

You can first determine the larger value by using min/max functions and then apply your formula. Example min/map and sqrt implementations: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol#L16-L28